# PostgreSQL FUNCTIONS error

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

Okay, for college I'm working on some SQL assignments but I can't figure out what's wrong here or whatever.. stuck at it for a couple of hours now.

So here I create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ins_notitie(pn_patient_nr VARCHAR, pn_notitie_datum DATE, pn_notitie_commentaar VARCHAR, lst_bijwerkdat DATE)
RETURNS void AS
$$
INSERT INTO patient_notitie(pn_patient_nr, pn_notitie_datum, pn_notitie_commentaar, lst_bijwerkdat)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Then I try to insert a new row:

```
SELECT ins_notitie('100001', now(), 'Test note', now());
```

Keep getting this error:

> ERROR:  function ins_notitie(unknown, timestamp with time zone, unknown, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT ins_notitie('100001', now(), 'Test note', now());
>                               ^
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: function ins_notitie(unknown, timestamp with time zone, unknown, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
>   SQL state: 42883
>   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   Character: 8

The function does get created as I can see in the GUI of postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says it cannot find the function with argument types you gave. `now()` returns a *timestamp*, not a *date* and a function accepting *timestamp* is not found.

You will be able to call the function with `now()::date` instead.

Comment: My god.... can't believe I didn't figure that out. Wow dude, you just made me a happy man!

Comment: @Nerotix: alternatively use `current_date` instead - that returns a `date`